# How Mongoose knows if query is finished?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to understand how mongoose code detects if query is finished and execute the query.

for example:

```
 const result=await this.find({})
```

In this case, mongoose trigger find.

```
   this.find({}).sort().limit(10)
```

In this case, mongoose trigger find sorted and limited.

How can mongoose code detects if there is chained method after `find`?

How mongoose does not start querying on find but wait for limit?
I am not too sure to be clear.

Comment: Chained methods don't _wait_ for anything. They operate sequentially. Each returns an object that can be operated on with the next function. So Mongoose does the find first, then sorts those records, then returns the the _limit_ amount of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mongoose query can be executed in one of two ways.

First, if you pass in a callback function, Mongoose will execute the query asynchronously and pass the results to the callback.

A query also has a .then() function or async/await, and thus can be used as a promise.

So basically when you append ".then" or "await" the query, Mongoose executes the query asynchronously.

So the code below won't execute a query until you pass a callback, append .then or await it.

```
this.find({}).sort().limit(10)
```

And chaining different methods to a query will modify that query till it's finally executed.

You can learn more about it here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html